# Recursive algorithm - extend vs creating new list with '+'

Tags: python, algorithm, recursion, combinations

So I have a recursive function below that keeps replacing `'_'` characters with each lowercase letter in the alphabet, until all combinations of those possible lowercase letters are substituted for the `'_'` characters.

**Simple Example**:

> `repl_underscores('__A')`
>
> `>>>[a_A,b_A,c_A......aaA,abA,acA....zzA]`

I had this function working with extend to build up the list, which as the comment below mentions, modifies the same existing list in-place repeatedly and accomplishes the job.

For the sake of practice, I wanted to re-write to build a new list on each call and pass that result to the successive recursive calls, with the goal of getting the same result.

It's not working and I know it has to do with the fact that I'm building up a new list on each call, but I thought that since I was passing in the built-up version on each recursive call that I would be OK since those calls would then be informed of changes.

I'm having trouble finding out where it is breaking.  I know I can get it to work by modifying the same list (either through mutable default, global variable, or extend), but I would like to build up a new clean list each time I recurse.

```
def repl_underscores(letters,res=None):
    if res is None: res = list()
    if '_' not in letters: return res
    repl = [letters.replace('_',letter,1) for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]
    res = res + repl #using += works, due to extending being a mutation (same list referenced at each call)
    for each in repl:
        repl_underscores(each,res) #trying to pass modified list to keep building up
    return res

print(repl_underscores('__DER'))
```

Comment: Did you try using ```print``` statements to see what is happening?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
res = res + repl #using += works, due to extending being a mutation (same list referenced at each call)
```

This line is the issue, as you seem to have guessed. Each time, in the recursive call, it assigns a *new local list*, which doesn't keep the reference to the old one, so the caller isn't notified of changes.

Luckily your function already returns the list, so let's just capture that:

```
     res = repl_underscores(each,res) #trying to pass modified list to keep building up
```

Comment: @Solaxun It's OK, i knew this because i got bitten with it a couple days ago. :)

Answer (score 1):

better to not modify the function arguments but build with the returned values (more functional style).  With slight modification of your code it works as intended.

import string

```
def repl_underscores(letters):
    res = list()
    if '_' not in letters: return res
    repl = [letters.replace('_',letter,1) for letter in string.ascii_lowercase]
    res += repl 
    for each in repl:
        res += repl_underscores(each) 
    return res

print(repl_underscores('__DER'))
```

Comment: I like this way of doing it as well, thank you for the response.

Answer (score -1):

Just use a function without recursion:

```
from itertools import combinations_with_replacement, chain

def repl_underscores(letters):
    result = []
    for chars in combinations_with_replacement(string.lowercase, letters.count('_')):
        chars = chain(chars,[''])
        result.append(''.join(a+next(chars) for a in letters.split('_')))
    return result
```